# Complex number equation solve

Tags: complex-numbers

Q1:

$$ \left(z+\frac1z\right)^ 5 = 1 $$

I can't figure out how this question is solved it or if it has a general form like $ck$.

Q2:
 Write a line : $ax + by + c = 0$ in complex number form.

Comment: 1. can you solve $w^5=1$? 2. $2x=z+\overline z$, $2iy=z-\overline z$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  1.yes

Comment: $$z=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{3}i)$$ or $$z=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{3}i)$$

Comment: please post only one question per post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Q1: Rewrite

$$z+\frac1z=\sqrt[5]1.$$

Multiplying by $z$ and rearranging, you get a quadratic equation:

$$z^2-\sqrt[5]1\,z+1=0.$$

Q2: As the equation is (presumably) in real numbers, the expression has no imaginary part. Then you can obtain the desired formula with

$$\Re(\bar wz)+c=0,$$ where $\bar w=a-ib$ and $z=x+iy$.

Comment: Which fifth root of 5?

Comment: @fleablood: don't fall in the trap. I used this notation on purpose, to leave the options opened. This is a hint, not a complete solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm a beginner at complex numbers. how should i proceed further?

Comment: @ErfanAhmadi: try harder.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is this Answer Right : $\frac{e^{i0 + \frac{2k\pi}{5}}\pm \sqrt{e^{i0 + \frac{4k\pi}{5}}- 4}}{2}$

Comment: @ErfanAhmadi: well done ! (But you should distribute $i$ on both terms.)